# Cannot write private member to an object whose class did not declare it at azure pipeline

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, azure-devops, async-await, playwright

> I'm trying to run playwright axe test cases on azure pipeline, but
> getting error at global-teardown.js file in azure pipeline,  but this
> run perfectly in local. Below are the respective files. I m trying to
> publish a HTML report in azure pipeline after running test cases.

```
//globalTeardown.js

const exec = require('child_process').execSync;

async function globalSetup() {
    > 5 |   await exec(
        |         ^
      6 |     "npx xunit-viewer -r  playwrightResults.xml -o playwrightResults.html "
      7 |   );
      8 | }

//playwright.config.js
const config = {
  globalSetup: "src/utils/globalSetup.js",
  testDir: "./a11ytests",
  globalTeardown: "src/utils/globalTeardown.js",
  use: {
    screenshot: "only-on-failure"
  },
  reporter: [["junit", { outputFile: "playwrightResults.xml" }]],
.
.
.
.}

//a11y.spec.js
const axeOption = {
  axeOptions: {
    runOnly: {
      type: "tag",
      values: ["best-practice"]
    }
  },
  detailedReport: true,
  detailedReportOptions: { html: true }
};

let browser;
let page;

test.describe("Playwright web page accessibility test for landing page", () => {
  test.beforeEach(async () => {
    browser = await chromium.launch();
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(ENV.BASE_URL);
    await injectAxe(page);
  });

  test("simple accessibility run for landing page", async () => {
    await checkA11y(page, null, axeOption);
  });
});
```

Comment: It was by me, I deleted it since it was not detailed and lacked other files

Comment: @JaromandaX are you familiar with this error?

Comment: In azure pipeline, its showing error at that line. I have pasted the code as shown in the pipeline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248096/discussion-between-abhishek-konnur-and-jaromanda-x).